# Regular Expression: Not all matches are printed when using System.out.println(m.matches());

Tags: java

I execute the following code:

```
public static void test() {
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("BIP[0-9]{4}E");

 Matcher m = p.matcher("BIP1111EgjgjgjhgjhgjgjgjgjhgjBIP1234EfghfhfghfghfghBIP5555E");
 System.out.println(m.matches());
 while(m.find()) {
  System.out.println(m.group());
 }
```

}

What i cannot explain is when the code is executed with **System.out.println(m.matches());** the matches printed are: **BIP1234E** and **BIP5555E**.
but when **System.out.println(m.matches());** is removed from code the matche **BIP1111E** is also printed.

Can someone please explain how that's possible ? Thnx a lot for your help.

Comment: This question is a little confusing, I think you mean to reference the System.out.println(m.group()) in your 2nd sentence?

Comment: @karianna No, it is not confusing. Last two matches will be printed in the loop, if `matches` is called before.

Comment: @khachik - You're quite right - tired eyes after devoxx ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matcher in Java maintains an index of found groups in the given string.

For example in the string provided in you example - BIP1111EgjgjgjhgjhgjgjgjgjhgjBIP1234EfghfhfghfghfghBIP5555E

There are 3 groups matching the pattern

BIP1111E
BIP1234E
BIP5555E

When matcher is created it starts from index 0. When we iterate over the matcher using m.find(), every time it finds a pattern it marks the index position of the found pattern.

For example the first gourp is at start of the string - that is it starts at 0 and goes till 7th (0 based index) character of the string. Next time we say find() it starts from 8th character to find next match of pattern.

m.matches tries to match the whole string and it also manipulates the internal index.

when you call m.matches() before iterating using m.find() the index is moved from the initial 0. so the first group of BIP1111E is skipped if you call m.matches()

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Matcher.reset` method to reset the matcher to its initial state after calling `matches`. That method changes the current state of the matcher object, and on the next call of `find` it starts looking after the first `g` character.